# How to compare a row in two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two data series i.e.

```
orders = pd.read_excel('Orders.xlsm')
customers = pd.read_excel('Customers.xlsm')
customers['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(customers['Order_Date']).dt.date
customers.drop(['Order_Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(orders, customers, on='Order ID')
prof = df.groupby(['date_column', 'Category']).sum()
prof = prof['Amount']
prof.head()
```

results into the below dataset

```
date_column  Category   
2018-01-04   Clothing        754
             Electronics    3289
             Furniture      1275
2018-01-05   Clothing        106
             Electronics     589
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

and

```
target = pd.read_excel('target.xlsm')
tar = target['Target']
tar.head()
```

Results into the below data set

```
0    10400
1    10500
2    10600
3    10800
4    10900
Name: Target, dtype: int64
```

I have to compare the row values of the `Amount` data series and `Target` data series. For that I used the following code:

```
target['Target_hit'] = np.where(tar['Target'] <= prof['Amount'], 1, 0)
```

But it gave this error:

```
KeyError: 'Target'
```

For reference I have added the jupyter notebook and the dataset [here](https://github.com/Samar-080301/help_needed)

Comment: `Tar` is a `series`. Just drop the `['Target']`.

Comment: If they have the same sizes, just compare the values

Comment: `target['Target_hit'] = np.where(tar['Target'] <= prof['Amount'], 1, 0)` Do i need to change this line?

Comment: how can i compare those 2 columns?

Comment: That is the line giving the error, since `tar` is a series which does not have an index value of `Target`; use `tar` in place of `tar['Target']` which should get rid of the `KeyError`. If you still have issues you will need to edit your question to give us more details about the problem.